# Bubble Chart in Chartjs not working

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I tried implementing the bubble chart as given on the official site of chartjs
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

but it only displays the grid without any data points.
It also does not show any errors.

Here's the code

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = [{x:10, y:10, r:10}];
// For a bubble chart
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
     options: {
     scales: {
       yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           beginAtZero:true,
            min: -30,
            max: 30  
           }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           beginAtZero:true,
            min: -30,
            max: 30  
           }
         }],
       }
     }
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart Js demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart-container" style="height:400px; width:400px">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="40" height="40"></canvas>    
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the **`data`** property incorrectly. It should be an **object** (consist of other properties) not an **array**.

So, you should use ...

```
...
data: {
   datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: data
   }]
},
...
```

instead of ...

```
...
data: data,
...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = [{
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   r: 10
}];
// For a bubble chart
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bubble',
   data: {
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Dataset 1',
         data: data
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               min: -30,
               max: 30
            }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               min: -30,
               max: 30
            }
         }],
      }
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container" style="height:400px; width:400px">
   <canvas id="myChart" width="40" height="40"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The data object should be structured differently.

For instance...

```
 data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: ["Label"],
            data: [{x: 3, y:4, r:5}]
        }]
    },
```